# combining object arrays in javascript to form a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am looking to merge 2 object arrays into 1 by matching them up by day and producing a new array of objects than contain the relevant data from the original 2. Currently i have these 2:

```
[
  { date: '9/30/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/1/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/2/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/3/2017', day: 'tuesday' },
  { date: '10/4/2017', day: 'wednesday' },
  { date: '10/5/2017', day: 'thursday' },
  { date: '10/6/2017', day: 'friday' },
  { date: '10/7/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/8/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/9/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/10/2017', day: 'tuesday' }
]
```

and

```
[
 {
    day: 'sunday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'monday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'tuesday',
    totalHours: 3,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'wednesday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'thursday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 7 }, { startTime: 20, stopTime: 23 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'friday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'saturday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
  }
]
```

my code to do this was as follows:

```
function finalFormat (a, d) {
  var combined = a.concat(d)
  var final = _(combined)
    .groupBy('day')
    .map(_.spread(_.assign))
    .value()
  return final
}
```

but my returned array:

```
[
  {
    date: '10/7/2017',
    day: 'saturday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/8/2017',
    day: 'sunday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/9/2017',
    day: 'monday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/10/2017',
    day: 'tuesday',
    totalHours: 3,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/4/2017',
    day: 'wednesday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/5/2017',
    day: 'thursday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 7 }, { startTime: 20, stopTime: 23 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/6/2017',
    day: 'friday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 } ]
  }
]
```

only has info for 7 dates, and i need the info for every date. so it should like like this:

```
[
 {
    date: '9/30/2017',
    day: 'saturday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
  },
{
    date: '10/1/2017',
    day: 'sunday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
{
    date: '10/2/2017',
    day: 'monday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/3/2017',
    day: 'tuesday',
    totalHours: 3,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/7/2017',
    day: 'saturday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/8/2017',
    day: 'sunday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/9/2017',
    day: 'monday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/10/2017',
    day: 'tuesday',
    totalHours: 3,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/4/2017',
    day: 'wednesday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/5/2017',
    day: 'thursday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 7 }, { startTime: 20, stopTime: 23 } ]
  },
  {
    date: '10/6/2017',
    day: 'friday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 } ]
  }
]
```

being new to js, i'm about to give up. can any of you smarter folks help me out?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at `reduce()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method. In addition, we can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection to have `O(1)` to access to the items while mapping collection:

```
const uniqueDays = new Map(secondArray.map(s => [s.day, s]));
const result = firstArray.map(({date, day})=> ({date, ...uniqueDays.get(day)}));
```

An example:

```js
const firstArray = [
  { date: '9/30/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/1/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/2/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/3/2017', day: 'tuesday' },
  { date: '10/4/2017', day: 'wednesday' },
  { date: '10/5/2017', day: 'thursday' },
  { date: '10/6/2017', day: 'friday' },
  { date: '10/7/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/8/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/9/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/10/2017', day: 'tuesday' }
];

const secondArray = [
  {
     day: 'sunday',
     totalHours: 10,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'monday',
     totalHours: 10,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'tuesday',
     totalHours: 3,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'wednesday',
     totalHours: 10,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'thursday',
     totalHours: 5,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 7 }, { startTime: 20, stopTime: 23 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'friday',
     totalHours: 5,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 } ]
   },
   {
     day: 'saturday',
     totalHours: 10,
     serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
   }
 ];

 const uniqueDays = new Map(secondArray.map(s => [s.day, s]));
 const result = firstArray.map(({date, day})=> ({date,  ...uniqueDays.get(day)}));
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [
  { date: '9/30/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/1/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/2/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/3/2017', day: 'tuesday' },
  { date: '10/4/2017', day: 'wednesday' },
  { date: '10/5/2017', day: 'thursday' },
  { date: '10/6/2017', day: 'friday' },
  { date: '10/7/2017', day: 'saturday' },
  { date: '10/8/2017', day: 'sunday' },
  { date: '10/9/2017', day: 'monday' },
  { date: '10/10/2017', day: 'tuesday' }
];

let b = [
 {
    day: 'sunday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'monday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 15, stopTime: 20 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'tuesday',
    totalHours: 3,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 2, stopTime: 5 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'wednesday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 15 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'thursday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 7 }, { startTime: 20, stopTime: 23 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'friday',
    totalHours: 5,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 } ]
  },
  {
    day: 'saturday',
    totalHours: 10,
    serveTimes: [ { startTime: 5, stopTime: 10 }, { startTime: 13, stopTime: 18 } ]
  }
];

let newArray = [];

a.forEach(function(aValue){
    b.forEach(function(bValue){
        if(aValue.day === bValue.day){
            aValue.totalHours = bValue.totalHours;
            aValue.serveTimes = bValue.serveTimes;
        }
    });
    newArray.push(aValue);
});
```

There are many ways to simplify this using `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, but this is an idea you can use to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are of uneven size -- first array has 11 objects, while the second array has only 7 objects.

- Find which array is bigger by comparing size with the `.length` property.
- Designate a key that all objects have in common (ie `"day"`).
- Loop through the larger array (ie first array -- in the demo its called `dates`).
- On each iteration of the larger array, loop through the smaller array (ie second array -- in the demo its called `hours`) find the key of current object and then match its value to that of the objects of the smaller array. For example, object in `dates` has `"day": "friday"` must match the object in `hours` that has `"day": "friday"`.
- On each match merge the objects with `Object.assign()`.

#### Demo

```js
let dates=[{date:"9/30/2017",day:"saturday"},{date:"10/1/2017",day:"sunday"},{date:"10/2/2017",day:"monday"},{date:"10/3/2017",day:"tuesday"},{date:"10/4/2017",day:"wednesday"},{date:"10/5/2017",day:"thursday"},{date:"10/6/2017",day:"friday"},{date:"10/7/2017",day:"saturday"},{date:"10/8/2017",day:"sunday"},{date:"10/9/2017",day:"monday"},{date:"10/10/2017",day:"tuesday"}],hours=[{day:"sunday",totalHours:10,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:15}]},{day:"monday",totalHours:10,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:10},{startTime:15,stopTime:20}]},{day:"tuesday",totalHours:3,serveTimes:[{startTime:2,stopTime:5}]},{day:"wednesday",totalHours:10,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:15}]},{day:"thursday",totalHours:5,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:7},{startTime:20,stopTime:23}]},{day:"friday",totalHours:5,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:10}]},{day:"saturday",totalHours:10,serveTimes:[{startTime:5,stopTime:10},{startTime:13,stopTime:18}]}];

const mergeByKV = (key, objectArrayA, objectArrayB) => {
  let primary, secondary;
  if (objectArrayA.length > objectArrayB.length) {
    primary = [...objectArrayA];
    secondary = [...objectArrayB];
  } else {
    primary = [...objectArrayB];
    secondary = [...objectArrayA];
  }
  let result = [];
  
  for (let objectA of primary) {
    let valueA = objectA[key];
    for (let objectB of secondary) {
      let valueB = objectB[key];
      if (valueA === valueB) {
        result.push(Object.assign(objectA, objectB));
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const schedule = mergeByKV('day', dates, hours);
console.log(JSON.stringify(schedule, null, 2));
```